# When I try To open a new link In HTML on my server, it combines the link with the server address and gives an error

Tags: python, html, web, server, webserver

Below is the code I am using. I am trying to get to ucc.managebac.com/student, but it takes me to 127.0.0.1:5000/ucc.managebac.com/student instead. Is there any way to fix this? Code in Python or HTML would work for me.

```
<form action="ucc.managebac.com/student" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="Managebac"
           name="Submit" id="frm1_submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried "https://ucc.managebac.com/student"? This should work.

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked. I completely forgot about adding https! Thanks again!